# Function inconsistent in requirements

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am just learning to code using the book "Think Python" and I'm so confused. The problem I ran into was in creating the flowers in TurtleWorld. The functions I am creating are not consistent in their requirements. First let me post the finished product, that actually works:

```
from swampy.TurtleWorld import*

world=TurtleWorld()
bob=Turtle()
print bob
bob.delay=.001

def polyline(t,n,length,angle):
    t=Turtle 
    print t
    for i in range(n):
        fd(bob,length)
        lt(bob,angle)

def arc(t, r, angle):
    t=Turtle
    arc_length=2*math.pi*r*angle/360
    n=int(arc_length/3)+1
    step_length=arc_length/n
    step_angle=float(angle)/n
    polyline(t,n,step_length,step_angle)

def petal(t,r,angle):
    for i in range(2):
        arc(t,r,angle)
        lt(t,180-angle)

def flower(t, n, r, angle):
    t=Turtle
    for i in range(n):
        petal(bob,r,angle)
        lt(bob,360/n)

flower(bob,5,77,99)

wait_for_user
```

On the function definition of `arc` and `petal`, `t` suffices for turtle, though when I began, using `t` in the definitions of `flower` and `polyline` returned an error unbound method(fd and lt). turtle instance required, got type instance instead.

The `t=Turtle` and `print turtle` added to half the function definitions were added after the fact to try and fix this error. This is the working version, I just want to know why it didn't work before. I'm not even sure why this worked, as I mainly put `bob` in as `t` out of frustration, I didn't actually expect it to work.

Comment: `bob = Turtle()` sets  `bob` to the results of evaluating the Turtle function. Try `bob = Turtle` (Note no parentheses) and removing the in-function assignments to t.

Answer (score 0):

Although I use Python's supplied turtle library below, instead of `swampy.TurtleWorld`, I don't think it makes a difference with respect to the issue you're having.  You seem to have a basic misunderstanding of formal parameters in function calls and the distinction between function calls and method invocations.  Consider this sequence of events:

```
flower(bob,5,77,99)
def flower(t, n, r, angle):
    t=Turtle
    ...
```

Here a perfectly good turtle, `bob`, gets passed in as the turtle argument `t` only to be immediately replaced with something else.  Or consider `polyline` which has a turtle argument `t` but instead the global `bob` gets used when a turtle is required.  Here's how I picture your program should come together:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from math import pi

def polyline(turtle, n, length, angle):
    for _ in range(n):
        turtle.fd(length)
        turtle.lt(angle)

def arc(turtle, radius, angle):
    arc_length = 2 * pi * radius * angle / 360
    n = int(arc_length / 3) + 1
    step_length = arc_length / n
    step_angle = float(angle) / n
    polyline(turtle, n, step_length, step_angle)

def petal(turtle, radius, angle):
    for _ in range(2):
        arc(turtle, radius, angle)
        turtle.lt(180 - angle)

def flower(turtle, n, radius, angle):
    for _ in range(n):
        petal(turtle, radius, angle)
        turtle.lt(360 / n)

screen = Screen()

bob = Turtle()

flower(bob, 5, 77, 99)

screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]